# Electron package does not open in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, electron

I have made a simple application that gets the filenames from a directory using electron framework with javascript, html and CSS. Installed node.js and npm on my windows and created the package for linux and windows using electron pacakager now the application packaged for windows is running perfectly fine in windwos but the package i created for linux is not running in linux, i click on the file with the name of the project and nothing happens. I tried running it from terminal but error is shown "Cannot access shared libraries"

I Searched a lot on google but did not found anything helpful
I don't know what maybe the issue, is there any program required to run it on linux.

Please help

following is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "productName": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Software",
  "main": "main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.10",
    "electron-packager": "^8.7.1",
    "readdirp": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --  platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Electron Tutorial App\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "author": AKB",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "readdirp": "^2.1.0"
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you create the Linux package under Windows?

Comment: @RoyalBingBong thanks for your response, yes i created it under windows but now i have fixed the error by typing "sudo apt install gconf2" command in ubuntu.